# Error when i try to run my app on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native module AudioRecorderManager tried to override AudioRecorderManager. 
        Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. 
        This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages() but is also automatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild.
        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:55)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1347)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1318)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1225)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

i get this when i try to run my app on android devise:
[image: i get this when i try to run my app on android devise]
'
...

```
 @Override
         protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
           @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
           List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
           // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
              packages.add(new ReactNativeAudioPackage());
              packages.add(new RNFSPackage());
           return packages;
         }
```

...'

when i try to run my app on android devise ,i get this error, knowing that it runs in IOS without problem

Comment: Have you followed the instructions displayed on the error message of your print screen?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `MainApplication.java`, and in particular protected `List<ReactPackage> getPackages()`; the `ReactNativeAudioPackage` is probably twice in the list.

If you have done automatic linking in your app, remove `ReactNativeAudioPackage` from `MainApplication.java`.

Comment: i checked 'MainApplication.java' ,but i don't even see `RNDeviceModule`in the list .